# return specific values from youtube

Tags: javascript, forms, function, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to write a small javascript function that will allow a user to submit a specific youtube channel url, and then return the number of views on that channel. Anyone have any idea?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to get the value of the attribute with the specified   namespaceURI and name</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var http;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
else  {xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

xhttp.open("GET","booksns.xml",false);
xhttp.send();
var xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;
var price=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("price")[0];
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML=price.getAttributeNS("http://www.w3schools.com/NS","currency");
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry for the simple code....its all ic ould find

Comment: why did you tag this question with "java"?

Comment: You've provided an example snippet of code that has nothing to do with the problem at hand. This tells me you are fairly unfamiliar with programming. You did visit w3schools, though, so I guess you can pick up some rudimentary Javascript knowledge. I'd also go to [CodeAcademy](http://www.CodeAcademy.com) to solidify your skillset and then go to [YouTube for Developers](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) to learn more about the YouTube API and how to integrate with it to yield the data you seek.